# Html-страница на телефоне не видит стили

Tags: html, css

Страница html отображается на пк вместе со стилями, а на телефоне стилей нет. В интернете увидел, что нужно добавить строку `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">`, но это не помогло. Как добавить стили в мобильную версию страницы?

```
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/sanitize.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Header</h2>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div class="i-1">
            <div class="menu"><p>Header of menu</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="i-2">
            <a href="#" class="menu">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="menu">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="menu">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="menu">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="menu">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="menu">Link</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <aside>
        <div class="aside"><p>Header of aside</p></div>
        <div class="aside"><p>Content of aside</p></div>
        <div class="aside"><p>Content of aside</p></div>
        <div class="aside"><p>Content of aside</p></div>
        <div class="aside"><p>Content of aside</p></div>
        <div class="aside"><p>Content of aside</p></div>
        <div class="aside"><p>Content of aside</p></div>
    </aside>
    <main>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Header</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eu ex venenatis, tristique ligula et, ornare ex. Ut ornare sagittis velit sit amet elementum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ornare semper neque, in dapibus tellus egestas ut. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum imperdiet, lorem sit amet vehicula tincidunt, ex nunc malesuada tortor, vitae convallis sem est a erat. Donec egestas pellentesque fermentum. Integer gravida ac urna feugiat condimentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tellus orci, varius ac feugiat sed, tempor ac lectus. Etiam vitae suscipit mi. Pellentesque sed nulla eget sapien commodo egestas in vitae dui. Nam fringilla interdum sodales. Ut erat nunc, consectetur ut mi at, tincidunt convallis velit.</p>
            <h3>Header</h3>
            <p>Nam vitae elementum nunc. Phasellus ac hendrerit arcu. Vivamus fermentum, arcu ut iaculis suscipit, nibh orci suscipit velit, et ornare dolor erat a massa. Nulla vulputate sapien non sem laoreet volutpat. Integer id eros vehicula, varius sem a, aliquet arcu. Nunc massa lacus, consectetur a est a, congue sollicitudin massa. Proin vitae est orci. Pellentesque imperdiet varius ex vehicula fermentum. Vivamus tristique est in magna fermentum malesuada. Praesent lacinia volutpat eros, non vehicula ligula lacinia vitae. Suspendisse sed velit consequat, congue ante at, dictum est. Quisque et dolor sit amet turpis tempus sagittis. Vestibulum efficitur tincidunt lacus, luctus semper arcu tempor non. Sed eget molestie velit, a hendrerit dolor.</p>
            <h3>Header</h3>
            <p>Praesent eu quam vel augue ullamcorper tempor eu et tortor. Suspendisse convallis ullamcorper tortor, vitae viverra tellus dapibus vel. Sed non pharetra libero. Nulla nec leo lobortis, fermentum erat eget, varius dolor. Suspendisse nec purus nec lectus congue posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam at nisi ac quam iaculis condimentum non at orci. Nulla eget venenatis lectus. Vivamus sed neque venenatis, fringilla nisi sit amet, laoreet risus. Fusce vitae gravida arcu. Aenean volutpat ut ipsum in iaculis. Nunc vitae blandit nisl, at faucibus velit. Aliquam iaculis mi tristique diam faucibus fermentum. Donec placerat arcu et dolor vulputate convallis.</p>
            <h3>Header</h3>
            <p>Vivamus a malesuada magna. Curabitur vel dignissim purus. Sed dictum nisi ut elementum congue. Etiam porttitor sit amet lectus nec elementum. Sed consequat mauris eget eros consequat tempus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce aliquam fermentum justo eu laoreet. Proin id dui a turpis convallis lacinia in in nibh. Sed eget elit ligula. Maecenas et erat imperdiet risus blandit imperdiet ac at risus. Aliquam quis erat eget elit posuere viverra. Quisque dictum interdum ante sed viverra.</p>
            <h3>Header</h3>
            <p>Sed sit amet lobortis nunc. Curabitur sem ante, scelerisque non erat non, mollis interdum risus. Pellentesque sit amet erat sit amet nibh scelerisque tincidunt eu eu diam. Fusce a fermentum enim, id vulputate nisl. Nunc porta gravida sem, in tincidunt erat hendrerit viverra. Curabitur sodales sem ante, id bibendum nisl cursus efficitur. Aenean dignissim ornare volutpat. Quisque ut augue accumsan, euismod tortor vitae, facilisis dolor. Maecenas faucibus turpis nunc. Suspendisse tristique malesuada erat, vitae fringilla ligula pretium et. Cras leo nisi, hendrerit eu porta sed, porta in velit. Aenean malesuada tempus consequat. Nulla at pretium nibh.</p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>Footer</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>


------


<style>
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 200px) minmax(200px, auto) minmax(150px, 20%);
    grid-template-rows: 75px auto 60px;
    grid-template-areas: "header header header"
                         "nav main aside" 
                         "footer footer footer";
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100vh;
}
header {
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, #D40000, #FF9B9B);
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-text-stroke: #FFF 0.3px;
    grid-area: header;
    padding: 5px;
    max-height: 75px;
}
nav {
    grid-area: nav;
    min-height: 80px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: linear-gradient( to top, #FFED53, #FF8400);
    text-align: left;
}
.menu,.menu:visited, .menu:hover {
    display: grid;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.i-1 {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
aside {
    grid-area: aside;
    background: linear-gradient( to top, #FFED53, #FF8400);
}
aside p {
    margin: 5px;
}
aside p:nth-child(1) {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.aside {
    height: 80px;
    align-content: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 20px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.aside p {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.aside:nth-child(1) {
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
.aside:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
main {
    grid-area: main;
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    font-size: 14px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #123456 0%, #23EEB7 100%);
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 5px;
    text-indent: 20px;
}
footer {
    display: grid;
    height: 60px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #004568, #85D0FF);
    grid-area: footer;
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    padding: 5px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}
footer p {
    align-self: end;
    font-size: 1em;
}
p {
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
}
/*----------------------------------*/
@media all and (min-width: 721px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    body {
        grid-template-columns: minmax(350px, auto) minmax(auto, auto);
        grid-gap: 0;
        grid-template-rows: 75px 1fr auto 60px;
        grid-template-areas: "header header"
                             "nav nav"
                             "main aside"
                             "footer footer";
    }
    nav, main, aside, footer {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    header {
        max-height: 75px;
    }
    aside {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    .i-2 {
        display: inline-flex;
        width: 90%;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .menu {
        min-width: 50px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .i-1 {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
/*------------------------------------*/
@media all and (max-width: 720px) {
    aside {
        display: none;
    }
    nav {
        display: inline-grid;
    }
    nav, main, footer {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    body {
        grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 2fr);
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr auto 1fr;
        grid-gap: 0;
        grid-template-areas: "header"
                             "nav"
                             "main"
                             "footer";
    }
    .i-2 {
        display: inline-flex;
        max-width: 90%;
        justify-content: space-around;
        margin: 5px 0;
    }
    .menu {
        padding: 5px;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .i-1 {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}

</style>
```

Comment: скинь код целиком

Comment: проблема может быть в media запросах в css

Comment: измените порядок подключения, я вывел ваши стили в низу страницы и все заработало

Comment: и кстати, сначала подключайте normalize

Comment: Если media или responsive.css стоит выше основных стилей, то она не будет применяться. причём это относится к определённому классу. Например если сначала прописали ".aside", а потом "media {.aside}" - media отработает, а если скажем "media {.aside}", а потом ".aside", то не отработает. И ещё для наглядности ".aside" -> "media{.aside}" -> "media{.main-content}" -> ".main-content", у ".aside" сработает, а у ".main-content" не сработает. P.S Стрелочки - это значит последовательность записи.